# Update wowza StreamPublisher schedule via REST API (or alternative)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wowza

Just getting started with Wowza Streaming Engine.

**Objective:**

- Set up a streaming server which live streams *existing* video (from S3) at a pre-defined schedule (think of a tv channel that linearly streams - you're unable to seek through).
- Create a separate admin app that manages that schedule and updates the streaming app accordingly.
- Accomplish this with as a little custom Java as possible.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to fetch / update `streamingschedule.smil` with the Wowza Streaming Engine REST API?

   There are methods to retrieve and update specific SMIL files via the REST API, but they only seem to be applicable to those created through the manager. [After all, `streamingschedule.smil` needs to be created manually by hand](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?145-How-to-schedule-streaming-with-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-(ServerListenerStreamPublisher)#schedules)
2. Alternatively, is it possible to reference a `streamingschedule.smil` that exists on an S3 bucket? (In a similar way footage can be linked from S3 buckets with the use of the MediaCache module)

   A comment [here (search for '3a')](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?145-How-to-schedule-streaming-with-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-(ServerListenerStreamPublisher)&page=11#comments) seems to indicate it's possible, but there's a lot of noise in that thread.

**What I've done:**

- [Set up Wowza Streaming Engine 4.4.1 on EC2](http://www.wowza.com/resources/WowzaStreamingEngineforEC2_UsersGuide.pdf)
- [Enabled REST API documentation](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?644-How-to-access-documentation-for-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-REST-API)
- Created a separate S3 bucket and filled it with pre-recorded footage
- [Enabled MediaCache on the server](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?121-How-to-scale-video-on-demand-streaming-with-Media-Cache) which points to the above S3 bucket
- Created a customised VOD edge application, with `AppType` set to `Live` and `StreamType` set to `live` in order to be able to point to the above (as suggested [here](https://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?16464-Play-VOD-file-as-a-Live-Stream-from-S3/page2&p=161297#post161297))
- [Created a StreamPublisher module with a `streamingschedule.smil` file](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?145-How-to-schedule-streaming-with-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-(ServerListenerStreamPublisher)#schedules)

The above all works and I have a working schedule with linearly streaming content pulled from an S3 bucket. Just need to be able to easily manipulate that schedule without having to manually edit the file via SSH.

So close! TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. No.  However, you can update it by creating an [http provider](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?733-How-to-create-an-HTTP-Provider) and having it handle the modifications to that schedule.  Should you want more flexibility here you can even extend the scheduler module to not require that file at all.
2. Yes.  You would have to modify the ServerListenerStreamPublisher solution to accomplish it.  Currently it solely looks a the local filesystem to read teh streamingschedule.smil file.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt. I've had some success mounting my S3 bucket with S3FS and changing the `content` path in my application-specific `Application.xml` to point to the S3FS volume. This accomplishes what I want (having a publicly accessible `streamschedule.smil` I can manipulate externally) – however, can you see any downsides to this approach compared to what you've suggested?

Comment: I'd suspect it would come down to how stable that mount remains.   I would definitely suggest doing some load testing prior to production release with that workflow.